# Python Merge Two Numpy Arrays Based on Condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

How can I merge the following two arrays, by looking up a value from array A in array B?

Array A:

```
array([['GG', 'AB', IPv4Network('1.2.3.41/26')],
       ['GG', 'AC', IPv4Network('1.2.3.42/25')],
       ['GG', 'AD', IPv4Network('1.2.3.43/24')],
       ['GG', 'AE', IPv4Network('1.2.3.47/23')],
       ['GG', 'AF', IPv4Network('1.2.3.5/24')]],
      dtype=object)
```

and Array B:

```
array([['123456', 'A1', IPv4Address('1.2.3.5'), nan],
       ['987654', 'B1', IPv4Address('1.2.3.47'), nan]],
      dtype=object)
```

The goal here is to create Array C, by looking up the IPv4Address from Array B in Array A and comparing them, and getting the corresponding array's second value and storing it:

Array C:

```
array([['123456', 'A1', IPv4Address('1.2.3.5'), nan, 'AF'],
       ['987654', 'B1', IPv4Address('1.2.3.47'), nan, 'AE']],
      dtype=object)
```

The ip addresses are of this type: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_network

How can I achieve this?

### edit:

*Please note* that the merging is conditioned on the IPs matching, so the resulting array C will have the same number of arrays as the Array B, but it will have one more value. The suggested duplicate links are not answering the same question.

Comment: Why would you do this with NumPy if you have Pandas? It is not really going to be any faster.

Comment: I get this error when I try to create your A array: `ValueError: 1.2.3.41/26 has host bits set`

Comment: @coldspeed i am trying to do it in pandas, i posed the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738799/python-improve-conditional-merge-of-big-pandas-dfs
but it is extremely slow

Comment: Check [Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), do a Ctrl+F search for "Merging only a single column from one of the DataFrames".

Comment: See 2nd answer of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370012/merging-numpy-arrays-together-with-a-common-dimension. It may help you

Comment: I try with python and get the error: `ValueError: 1.2.3.41/26 has host bits set`. Please check your code again.

Comment: @huynhsamha this is dummy data, i haven't put real ip addresses, maybe that is why

Comment: Then please make an effort to ensure the data is valid, so it can _at least_ be copy pasted and run.

Comment: Are the CIDR blocks guaranteed not to overlap? If they do, which should be picked, smallest or largest?

Comment: In terms of algorithmic complexity, A and B both are up to `2**32` in size, but the `/length` has at most 32 values for IPv4 -- it may be best to do 32 lookups, e.g.: `1.2.3.5 -> 0b1000000100000001100000101 -> 0b1000000100000001100000100 -> 0b1000000100000001100000100 -> 0b1000000100000001100000000 -> ....`

Comment: The only answer you need is that object-dtype numpy arrays are pointless, they don't offer you the speed or memory advantage why we use numpy in the first place. Just use a list and get it over with in native python.

Answer (score 6):

This should do what you asked for (at least the output is exactly what you wanted), I made some minor assumptions to deal with your #dummydata, but that should not matter too much.

> Code:

```
import numpy as np
import ipaddress as ip

array_A = np.array([['GG', 'AB', ip.ip_network('192.168.0.0/32')],
                    ['GG', 'AC', ip.ip_network('192.168.0.0/31')],
                    ['GG', 'AD', ip.ip_network('192.168.0.0/30')],
                    ['GG', 'AE', ip.ip_network('192.168.0.0/29')],
                    ['GG', 'AF', ip.ip_network('192.168.0.0/28')]],
                   dtype=object)

array_B = np.array([['123456', 'A1', ip.ip_network('192.168.0.0/28'), np.nan],
                    ['987654', 'B1', ip.ip_network('192.168.0.0/29'), np.nan]],
                   dtype=object)


def merge_by_ip(A, B):
    # initializing an empty array with len(B) rows and 5 columns for the values you want to save in it
    C = np.empty([len(B), 5],dtype=object)
    for n in range(len(B)):
        for a in A:
            # checking condition: if ip address in a is ip address in b
            if a[2] == B[n][2]:
                # add the entry of b with the second value of a to the new Array c
                C[n] = np.append(B[n], a[1])
    return C


print(merge_by_ip(array_A, array_B))
```

> Output:

```
[['123456' 'A1' IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/28') nan 'AF']
 ['987654' 'B1' IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/29') nan 'AE']]
```

> *Note:*

This solution has `O(m * n)` complexity, which isn't necessary, there are many out-of-the box (`Pandas`) and custom (e.g. using `dict`) ways to merge with lower complexity.

Comment: could you please comment some of the values? for example:
what is 5 in `np.empty([len(B), 5]` and what is 3 in `a[2]`, `B[n][2]`, `a[1]` ?

Comment: I added it within the code. I do not understand what you mean by 3 though.

Answer (score 3):

There appears no reason you *can't* use Pandas. If your IP addresses align perfectly, you can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then use [`pd.DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) to return a NumPy array:

```
import pandas as pd

# data from @mk18
df_A = pd.DataFrame(array_A[:, 1:], columns=['', 'IP'])
df_B = pd.DataFrame(array_B, columns=['id', 'value', 'IP', 'na'])

res = df_B.merge(df_A, on='IP').values

print(res)

array([['123456', 'A1', IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/28'), nan, 'AF'],
       ['987654', 'B1', IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/29'), nan, 'AE']],
      dtype=object)
```

If you wish to ignore the network component and include only the [`network_address`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.network_address) when merging, i.e. use `'1.2.3.5'` instead of `'1.2.3.5/24'`, then you can create helper series before merging:

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import attrgetter

df_A = pd.DataFrame(array_A[:, 1:], columns=['key', 'IP'])
df_B = pd.DataFrame(array_B, columns=['id', 'value', 'IP', 'na'])

df_A['IP_NoNetwork'] = df_A['IP'].map(attrgetter('network_address'))
df_B['IP_NoNetwork'] = df_B['IP'].map(attrgetter('network_address'))

res = df_B.merge(df_A.drop('IP', 1), on='IP_NoNetwork')\
          .loc[:, ['id', 'value', 'IP', 'na', 'key']].values
```

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your data and complications that prevent you from using `join_by` or `rec_join` as the question you linked suggested.

The main issue with your data, as pointed out by others, is that networks like `IPv4Network('1.2.3.4/24')` are not valid networks, since they have host bits set that are masked out by the `/24`. The `/24` means that the final `32 - 24 = 8` bits are your hosts bits and the constructor for `IPv4Network` requires that these are set to 0, for example `IPv4Network('1.2.3.0/24')` is valid.

The main complication is that you have **networks** in one array, but **addresses** in the other. Methods like `rec_join` and `join_by` use comparison (i.e. `==`) to decide what records go together. Some of the other proposed answers 'solve' this by replacing your networks with addresses, but that doesn't appear to be your problem.

Also, note that a single network address may fall into multiple different networks. For example, `IPv4Address('1.2.3.129')` falls within both `IPv4Network('1.2.3.0/24')` and `IPv4Network('1.2.3.128/25')`. So, I assume you'd expect both matches to show up in your results.

To join addresses from one array to networks that the address actually falls within, you'll have to iterate over the array yourself and construct a new one. The type of comparison that works is `IPv4Address('1.2.3.129') in IPv4Network('1.2.3.0/24')` (this is `True`).

A working code example bringing this together:

```
from numpy import nan, asarray, concatenate
from ipaddress import IPv4Address, IPv4Network

a = asarray([
    ['GG', 'AA', IPv4Network('1.2.4.0/24')],
    ['GG', 'AB', IPv4Network('1.2.3.128/25')],
    ['GG', 'AC', IPv4Network('1.2.3.0/24')]
], dtype=object)

b = asarray([
    ['123456', 'A1', IPv4Address('1.2.3.4'), nan],
    ['987654', 'B1', IPv4Address('1.2.3.129'), nan],
    ['024680', 'C1', IPv4Address('1.2.4.0'), nan]
], dtype=object)


def join_addresses_networks(addresses, networks):
    for address in addresses:
        for network in networks:
            if address[2] in network[2]:
                yield concatenate((address, network[:-1]))


c = asarray(list(join_addresses_networks(b, a)))

print(c)
```

Comment: This solution has O(m * n) complexity, which isn't necessary here, there are many out-of-the box (Pandas) and custom (e.g. using `dict`) ways to merge with lower complexity.

Comment: You are right @jpp but I figured a straightforward answer was the better answer, since the questions isn't so much about performance and more about a basic "how to". The answer could be amended for efficiency to O(m + n), left as an exercise for the reader.